# Define Dynamic Named Query in Entity Class

Tags: java, jpa, entity, named-query

I have a named query as below;

@NamedQuery(name = "MyEntityClass.findSomething", query = "SELECT item FROM MyTable mytbl")

Now I need to append dynamic sort clause to this query (based on UI input params)

So my question is can I still define the NamedQuery inside the Entity class.

I have used StringBuffer to define the named query in my Business Impl class and dynamically appended values for the sort order/sort colum.

Answer (score 0):

Named queries in JPA are not changeable. They behave like constants. The only thing you can do with them is to define a **fixed number of parameters** in theirs body.

If you want to dynamicly build a query use a normal JPQL query instead of named one.